# Valor perde conteúdo assim que sai do ajax

Tags: ajax

Quando eu tento pegar o valor, fora do ajax, ele perde o valor, porque?

```
    var url = window.location;
var id = url.toString().split("=")[1];
var nomeResponsavel = "",nomeEmpresa = "" ,emailEmpresa,telefone,site,rua,numero, bairro,estado,cidade,cep;

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'load-data.php?id='+id,
    dataType: 'text',
    success: function(data) {
        msg = data;
        var values = $.parseJSON(msg);
        nomeEmpresa = values[0].razao_social;
        emailEmpresa = values[0].email_comercial;
        telefone = values[0].tel_comercial;
        site = values[0].siteweb;
        rua = values[0].end_logradouro;
        numero = values[0].end_numero;
        bairro = values[0].end_bairro;
        estado = values[0].end_eatado;
        cidade = values[0].end_cidade;
        cep = values[0].end_cep;
        nomeResponsavel = values[0].nome;


    },
    error:function(e){
        console.log(e)
    }
});
alert(nomeResponsavel);
```

**Código total da página**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>



    <?php
    require_once("cabecalho.php");
    ?>
</head>
</html>
<body>
<!-- /. WRAPPER  -->
<!-- SCRIPTS -AT THE BOTOM TO REDUCE THE LOAD TIME-->
<!-- JQUERY SCRIPTS -->
<script src="assets/js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<!-- BOOTSTRAP SCRIPTS -->
<script src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- METISMENU SCRIPTS -->
<script src="assets/js/jquery.metisMenu.js"></script>
<!-- CUSTOM SCRIPTS -->
<script src="assets/js/custom.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">


    var url = window.location;
    var id = url.toString().split("=")[1];
    var nomeResponsavel = "",nomeEmpresa = "",emailEmpresa,telefone,site,rua,numero, bairro,estado,cidade,cep;


    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'load-data.php?id='+id,
        dataType: 'text',
        success: function(data) {
            msg = data;
            var values = $.parseJSON(msg);
            nomeEmpresa = values[0].razao_social;
            emailEmpresa = values[0].email_comercial;
            telefone = values[0].tel_comercial;
            site = values[0].siteweb;
            rua = values[0].end_logradouro;
            numero = values[0].end_numero;
            bairro = values[0].end_bairro;
            estado = values[0].end_eatado;
            cidade = values[0].end_cidade;
            cep = values[0].end_cep;
            nomeResponsavel = values[0].nome;


        },
        error:function(e){
            console.log(e)
        }
    });



    var myUrl = encodeURIComponent("http://ecoprintq.com/index.php/partnerApplication/create");
    var dados = "User_full_name:"+nomeEmpresa+"&User_institution:sssss"
    $.ajax({
        url: "webproxy.php?url=" + myUrl,
        data: dados,
        crossDomain:true,
        type: "GET",
        timeout: 30000,
        dataType: "text", // "xml", "json"

        success: function(data) {
            //window.location.href = "webproxy.php?url=" + myUrl + "&" + dados;
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, ex) {
            alert(textStatus + "," + ex + "," + jqXHR.responseText);
        }
    });


</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sim, isso é porque `alert(nomeResponsavel);` é executado antes do retorno da requisição ajax, qualquer coisa que querias fazer com esse valor deve estar dentro do `success` ou `completed` do obj que passas para a função `$.ajax()`, podes fazer isto:

```
function fazer_o_suposto_com_este_valor(responsavel) {
    alert(responsavel);
}
...
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'load-data.php?id='+id,
    dataType: 'text',
    success: function(data) {
        ....
        nomeResponsavel = values[0].nome;            
    },
    error:function(e){
        console.log(e);
        nomeResponsavel = 'Não há, ocorreu um erro';
    },
    complete: function() {
        fazer_o_suposto_com_este_valor(nomeResponsavel);
    }
});
```

Exemplo:

```js
function fazer_o_suposto_com_este_valor(responsavel) {
  alert(responsavel);
}
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: 'https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/maxitem.json',
  success: function(data) {
    nomeResponsavel = data;            
  },
  error:function(e){
    nomeResponsavel = 'Não há, ocorreu um erro';
  },
  complete: function() {
    fazer_o_suposto_com_este_valor(nomeResponsavel);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Na verdade, eu queria pegar esse valor do ajax e enviar para um outro ajax, só que envia.
Um captura e outro envia

Comment: Coloquei até o código total da página.
Queria pegar o valor que recebo de um ajax e enviar para outro ajax

Comment: Usando este exemplo podes colocar o novo envio dentro da função `fazer_o_suposto_com_este_valor`, que neste momento tem só o alert mas podes processar o que quiseres lá... Fazer um novo pedido inclusive @Gabrielfalieri

Comment: valeu meu caro, deu certinho

Comment: @Gabrielfalieri de nada. Ainda bem que resolveste

Comment: Cara, tu flagra se tem como, ao envés de enviar, como se fosse um post, apenas preencher o formulário cross-domain?

Comment: Pois tem um captcha nesse form que estou enviando as informações, e o captcha está me regaçando

Answer (score 2):

Uma requisição AJAX é um processo assíncrono. O que isso quer dizer é que não necessariamente ocorre na mesma sequencia síncrona de execução do seu código, que é indo de cima pra baixo percorrendo o código.

Logo, quando você tenta acessar o valor da variável que é setada pelo AJAX, tem grandes chances da requisição não ter executado ainda, e esse valor não tenha sido setado, ainda que você faça essa instrução abaixo da chamada AJAX.

Te recomendo dar uma lida em [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) que são uma das formas de trabalhar com essas situações em Javascript. E em [AJAX](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started) pra entender melhor o que tá acontecendo ali.

Answer (score 0):

Verifique a versão do jQuery que você está utilizando antes de usar `success` ou `error`.

> Aviso Deprecation: A jqXHR.success(), jqXHR.error()e
>   jqXHR.complete()as chamadas de retorno são removidos a partir de
>   jQuery 3.0. Você pode usar jqXHR.done(), jqXHR.fail()e,
>   jqXHR.always()em vez disso.

```
var url = window.location;
var id = url.toString().split("=")[1];
var nomeResponsavel = "",nomeEmpresa = "" ,emailEmpresa,telefone,site,rua,numero, bairro,estado,cidade,cep;

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'load-data.php?id='+id,
    dataType: 'text' 
})
.done( function( data ) {
    msg = data;
    var values = $.parseJSON(msg);
    nomeEmpresa = values[0].razao_social;
    emailEmpresa = values[0].email_comercial;
    telefone = values[0].tel_comercial;
    site = values[0].siteweb;
    rua = values[0].end_logradouro;
    numero = values[0].end_numero;
    bairro = values[0].end_bairro;
    estado = values[0].end_eatado;
    cidade = values[0].end_cidade;
    cep = values[0].end_cep;
    nomeResponsavel = values[0].nome;
    alert(nomeResponsavel);
})
.fail( function( e ) {
    console.log(e)
});
```

**Referência:** http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/